# Gather all email address from selected table cells

Tags: jquery, html-table, href, mailto

I'm helping out someone who runs a website...

I've been given an example table for which we can assume ***I do not have control over the generated html***.

The goal is to be able to click some TD rows and email the address of the anchor's href contained within (after clicking a button I also inserted via jQuery).  Upon clicking a cell, I highlight the cell yellow (for now).

How do I get the value for the mailto: for highlighted cells after clicking the "Email Selected" button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background", "yellow");
    });
           
    $("body").append("<div align=\"center\"><a class=\"emailAll\" href=\"#\">Email Selected</a></div>");
    $(".emailAll").click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
        alert($("a").parent("font").parent("div").parent( "td" ).val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" align="left">
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>MONDAY</strong></font></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">TUESDAY</font></strong></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">WEDNESDAY</font></strong></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">THURSDAY</font></strong></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">FRIDAY</font></strong></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font size="2"></font></font></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font size="2"></font></font></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"></div>
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td rowspan="3" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font size="2"></font></font></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" rowspan="4" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"> 
            <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="mailto:jdoe@somewhere.net">John 
              &amp; Doe</a></font></div>
          </div>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" rowspan="3" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Joan 
            Y.</font></div>
        </div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="120" rowspan="2" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
        <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="mailto:janel@gmail.com">Jane 
            L</a></font></div>
        </div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" rowspan="2" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="mailto:elmo@yahoo.com">Elmo</a></font></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" rowspan="2" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"></div>
          <a href="mailto:cookie@gmail.com"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Cookie</font></a></div></td>
      <td height="22" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" rowspan="4" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="mailto:bigbird@hotmail.com">Big 
          &amp; Bird</a></font> </div></td>
      <td height="22" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting all possible email targets ( some of the cells are empty or doesn't have a mailto address) You can collect the data with the filter & map functions.

I made a quick demo and added the option to deselect a cell and a button to clear all:

**Demo:** [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zmfkjoz/)

**The code:**

Select & deselect:

```
// Add a click listener to each table cell and toggle state on more clicks:
$("td").click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('chosen'))
        $(this).css("background", $(this).attr("bgcolor")).data('chosen', false);
    else
        $(this).css("background", "yellow").data('chosen', true);
});
```

Add buttons:

```
// Append the action button and clear all button:
$("body").append("<br /><div><button class=\"emailAll\">Email Selected</button><button class=\"clearAll\">Clear All Selected</button></div>");
```

Collect Emails (click event):

```
// Collect all email addresses from the selected cells:
$('.emailAll').on('click', function(){
    allSelected = $('td').filter(function(){
           return $(this).data("chosen") === true;
    }).map(function(){
        var target = $(this).find('a').eq(0);
        if ($(target).length && typeof $(target).attr('href') !== 'undefined')
        return  target.attr('href').replace('mailto:','');
    }).get();
    emailAllAction(allSelected);
    /* Debug */
    console.log(allSelected);
});
```

Function to execute after collected emails:

```
//Function to use all collected emails:
function emailAllAction(allSelected) {
    if (allSelected.length) {
        alert('Will email to: \r' + allSelected.join('\r'));
    } else {
        alert('No Email address found in your selections!');
    }
}
```

Clear all button (click event):

```
//Clear button:
$('.clearAll').click(function(){
    $("td").each(function(){
        if ($(this).data('chosen')) $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Have Fun.

Answer (score 3):

I forked and updated your fiddle. Non-email table-cells get filtered now and the resultlist will be logged to the console.

https://jsfiddle.net/tLeymxhk/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Add a click listener to each table cell
$('td').click(function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'yellow').data('selected', true);
});

// Append the action button
$('body').append('<div><button class=\'emailAll\'>Email Selected</button>');

// Collect all email addresses from the selected cells
$('.emailAll').on('click', function(){

  var results = $('td')
  .filter(function(){
      // Only keep the ones that got a data-selected flag and a mailto-link
      return $(this).data('selected') && $(this).find('a[href^="mailto:"]').length > 0;
    })
  .map(function(){
      return $(this).find('a').attr('href').replace('mailto:','');
    })
  .get();

    // Output the results                  
    $.each( results, function( index, value ) {
      console.log(index + ': ' + value);
    });

  });    

});
```

Comment: The only other thing I might add is a regex to match and validate the email address. `var pattern = /mailto:(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)/i`

Answer (score 1):

### Use one handler to modify "Email selected" link on each cell click

A single handler toggles a `.selected` class on clicked cells, then checks for the existence of a child `mailto:` link. If it exists, the recipient is either appended to or removed from the `.emailAll` link. Now the `.emailAll` link is just a normal "mailto:" link with a dynamically updated list of recipients.

```
$("td").click(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.toggleClass('selected');
    if ($el.has('a[href^="mailto:"]').length) {
        var recipient = $el.find('a').attr('href').replace('mailto:','');
        $('.emailAll').attr('href', function (i, href) {
            if (href.match(recipient)) {
                return $(this).attr('href').replace(recipient + ',', '');
            } else {
                return $(this).attr('href') + recipient + ',';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In this way, you can control style and state with a single event handler. No need to modify the CSS with JS or create an expensive second click handler for the `.emailAll` link that filters the table.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').click(function () {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.toggleClass('selected');
        if ($el.has('a[href^="mailto:"]').length) {
            var recipient = $el.find('a').attr('href').replace('mailto:','');
            $('.emailAll a').attr('href', function (i, href) {
                if (href.match(recipient)) {
                    return $(this).attr('href').replace(recipient + ',', '');
                } else {
                    return $(this).attr('href') + recipient + ',';
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('body').append('<div class="emailAll"><a href="mailto:">Email Selected</a></div>');     
});
```

```css
.selected {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.emailAll {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="0" align="left">
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>MONDAY</strong></font></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">TUESDAY</font></strong></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">WEDNESDAY</font></strong></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">THURSDAY</font></strong></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="46" nowrap bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">FRIDAY</font></strong></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font size="2"></font></font></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font size="2"></font></font></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"></div>
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td rowspan="3" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font size="2"></font></font></font></div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666"> <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" rowspan="4" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"> 
            <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="mailto:jdoe@somewhere.net">John 
              &amp; Doe</a></font></div>
          </div>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
 <tr> 
      <td width="120" rowspan="3" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Joan 
            Y.</font></div>
        </div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" height="22" nowrap bgcolor="#666666">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="120" rowspan="2" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
        <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
          <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="mailto:janel@gmail.com">Jane 
            L</a></font></div>
        </div></td>
      <td width="120" nowrap bgcolor="#666666">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" rowspan="2" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="mailto:elmo@yahoo.com">Elmo</a></font></div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td width="120" rowspan="2" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <div align="center"> 
          <div align="center"></div>
          <a href="mailto:cookie@gmail.com"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Cookie</font></a></div></td>
      <td height="22" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="120" rowspan="4" nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="mailto:bigbird@hotmail.com">Big 
          &amp; Bird</a></font> </div></td>
      <td height="22" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are appending the content dynamically, you need to use event delegation for attaching the events to dynamically generated elements

and you can use jquery filter function to only get td elements that have css background color yellow:

```
 $("body").on('click','.emailAll',function(){
    alert("clicked");
    var selectedtd = $('td').filter(function(){
     return $(this).css("background")=="yellow";
    });
    return false;
});
```

for getting all the mailto values in array:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
  return $(this).css("background")=="yellow";
}).map(function(){
  return $(this).find('a').attr('href').replace('mailto:','');
}).get();
```

Comment: That is definitely helpful in getting the highlighted cell as an object, but how do I get the value for the mailto: within the highlighted cells?

Comment: I must be missing something, no values are printed out.  Here's it set up in jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/rwguhokt/2/